# R9 270x with AMDGPU driver under Ubuntu 16.04 with new 4.9 kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics

I heard that the newest mainline kernel should be capable of using the AMD-GPU driver for my AMD R9 270x graphics card.
However, I could not find any information on how to set it up under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Would it be sufficient to install the new kernel (from here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9/) and enable "amdgpu" in the xorg.conf? Or what is the correct way to install it?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid here, but shouldn't it be listed under "proprietary drivers" in Software Settings like other drivers and let it set itself up?

Comment: Kernel version 4.9.1 came out a couple days ago. Although it didn't have the huge amounts of rewrites for `AMDGPU` like 4.9, it includes them plus has some minor bug fixes. Therefore 4.9.1 should be installed instead of 4.9. Linux Kernel 4.9 is a LTS (Long Term Support) release and will be used by Ubuntu 17.04. It's very easy to install and reboot your computer to see how it works. If you have any problems you can simply reboot with Kernel 4.4.0-57 or whatever is current within Ubuntu 16.04 on your machine.

Comment: This article by gentoo identifies your GPU R9 270X  (Southern Islands, Pitcairn) and the firmware binaries provided since Kernel 4.9-rc1: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMDGPU

Comment: If I install the 4.9.1 kernel, Xorg.log tells me that still the RADEON driver is used. So back to my question. What steps are necessary to actually use amdgpu?

Comment: @willem.hill amdgpu-**pro** is the "proprietary driver" from amd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to have the latest kernel with amdgpu module and the latest AMD firmware (amdgpu-pro) in place, then try to set it for example in:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf
```

like this:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "AMD"
  Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

KMS must be enabled and amdgpu not being blacklisted. This should already do the trick. You could as well blacklist radeon module.

Not sure if your card is a "Southern Islands" or "Sea Islands" if this is the case you might need to compile a kernel on your own if:

```
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_CIK=Y
```

or

```
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_SI=Y
```

are not set in the kernel config. Which option to choose depends on your gfx card.

When changing gfx settings you're always in near **danger** that X doesn't start any more. It's a good idea having a 2nd computer for surfing documentation.

Folks I'm sorry I can't verify my answer because I've got no amd card. So please be kind.

This is a summary from:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU
- The top of my head
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMDGPU

Comment: Thank you for this summary. It should be noted that a more detailed explanation for these steps can be found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot later when I am able. The R9 270X (Pitcairn) is a southern islands card, BTW.